# C string padding to separate two strings to fixed width

Tags: c, string, printf, padding

I'm trying to print a list in C that lines up the index of the list and a colon to the ouput as follows:

```
...
8  : SOME STUFF
9  : MORE STUFF
10 : MORE STUFF BUT LESS PADDING
...
100: MORE STUFF BUT NO PADDING
...
```

I'm currently using:

```
printf("$%d", index);
printf(":"): // this is the line that needs changing
printf(" some stuff");
```

Comment: `printf("%-3d:", index);` will do the job of the first two lines.  Your output doesn't show a `$` so I removed it from the format.  Read the (POSIX) specification of [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for information on how that works — or your system's manual pages.  Read it often — several times a day for the first week, several times a week for the next month, and monthly for the rest of the first year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 42, 999 };
enum { NUM_ARRAY = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[ 0 ] ) };
for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAY; ++i ){
    printf( "%-3d: sometext\n", array[ i ] );
}
```

This is a for-loop through an array. Every array-item will be printed with a padding of three.

Output:

```
1  : sometext
2  : sometext
3  : sometext
4  : sometext
5  : sometext
6  : sometext
7  : sometext
42 : sometext
999: sometext
```